# Open + simply connected + antipodal + proper set in the sphere

Tags: general-topology, spheres

It seems to me that if $U\subseteq\mathbb S^n$ is open, simply connected and proper, there must exist some point $x\in U$ such that $-x\notin U$. Otherwise, $U=-U$, and $U$ would satisfy the conditions of the title. Could such a subset exist?

Comment: Let $A\subset\Bbb S^n$ be any finite set. Then $\Bbb S^n\setminus (A\cup -A)$ is open, connected, antipodal and proper. -- Or let $U$ be *any* (relatively) open, connected, proper subset of the closed disk; transport $U$ to $\Bbb S^n$ by identifying the disk with the closed northern hemisphere and take the union of it with its southern mirror image

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen many thanks. I need to add some additional hypothesis then.

Comment: Sorry, the second (i.e., mirror image) construction won' guarantee antipodality; but that can certainly be mended in order to obtain a wide range of open connected antipodal proper subsets

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb S^n$ minus its two poles is a proper, open, antipodal subset of $\Bbb S^n$. As it is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$ minus a point, it is also simply connected as soon as $n\ge 3$.

I suppose, you do not want that all $\Bbb S^1\to U$ can be contracted to a point but rather all $\Bbb S^{n-1}\to U$?

Comment: Thanks again. I'm mostly interested in $\mathbb S^2$. I want to map the exterior of a disc (i.e., homeomorphic to the $\mathbb R^2$ disc) around $(0,0,1)$ onto its interior. I'm not finding the right hypothesis to my question though.